# Hide querystring parameters from url in response.sendRedirect

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a java servlet that is redirecting to a web application on a different server.

I was wondering if there is a way to hide the querystring parameters, so they are not visible to the client in the address bar.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.mywebapp.com/login.html?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2");
```

Is there a way to force the sendRedirect to POST to the page and hide the querystring?

Edit: use case.

- A user goes to http://www.mywebapp.com
- They are automatically redirected to my servlet filter
- The servlet handles SSO to an Identity provider using SAML
- Once it recieves the SAML response back, I redirect the now authenticated user back to mywebapp.com
- I want to pass some parameters back to the webapp. Parameters from the SAML response. But I don't want the user to see them in the URL

Clearly, sendRedirect() is not what I want. What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could connect to the other server from your servlet (`HttpConnection`) and copy the returned data. The user will only see your server.

An alternative is returning an HTML page that does send a POST form automatically after loading. The user will need to allow JS.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use POST in this scenario. When calling `sendRedirect()` this is what you send back to the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.mywebapp.com/login.html?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

Browser interprets this and points user to that location.

Something tells me (maybe `login.html` name and two parameters) that you want to automatically login user on some web site). Don't go this way, sending username/password (both using GET parameters and inside POST) is really insecure.

Without knowing much about your use case it's probably the best solution to call `http://www.mywebapp.com/login.html` from your servlet, parse the response and return it to the user (so he will never really see `mywebapp` in his browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my initial post with a more specific use case. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward the request from server side and then at the end redirect to some other page

Answer (score 0):

I found a way for hiding any string from Java or Android project with concept of inner classes using proguard to hide them [a class is my server side processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEi9s.png)

Comment: Kindly do not post images of code, but include the code in your Answer.