# Accesing URL from external server and hiding real URL to users (kinda allowing forward to external servers)

Tags: java, servlets, url-rewriting

Here is my problem. I have a JavaEE7 Web App deployed on Tomcat 7, say at *www.myapp.com/hello/*. Some pages need to access static resources (images, PDFs) located at a different host, say *www.resources.com/resource?id=nnn&pwd=mmm* where I cannot change anything but:

1. I need to hide the actual url from the final users for security reasons
2. I still need to do some security checkings in my host before allowing forward/sendredirect.

I considered forward, but it is a different host. Not an option. Am I right?

I considered sendRedirect, but it sends the new url to the browser along with a 302 and that breaks point 1, correct?

I also had a look at [Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter example](http://david.feinzeig.com/blog/2013/05/13/use-tomcat-url-rewriting-to-serve-external-images-for-atlassian-jira-avatars/) but couldn't find how to overcome forward and sendRedirect with the filter and meeting both requirements

The idea of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730410/hide-querystring-parameters-from-url-in-response-sendredirect) is not optimal as the servlet is a mediator and consumes my Tomcat's resources.

Any idea?. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered [proxying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)? And [cacheing](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/BasicAccelerator)? Also, I hope you have the copyright holders permission.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, no copyright issues. I'd need to solve this with Tomcat, no Apache to proxy or mod url rewrite

Comment: You could try [this](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet) proxy servlet. I've used it myself in the past, it works fine.